# Scala: How to find the minimum of more than 2 elements?

Tags: scala, math, minimum

Since the Math.min() function only allows for the use of 2 elements, I was wondering if there is maybe another function which can calculate the minimum of more than 2 elements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is `.min` on just about anything that vaguely resembles a sequence of elements or a collection of some sort.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have multiple elements you can just chain calls to the min method:

```
Math.min(x, Math.min(y, z))
```

Since scala adds the a `min` method to numbers via implicits you could write the following which looks much fancier:

```
x min y min z
```

If you have a list of values and want to find their minimum:

```
val someNumbers: List[Int] = ???
val minimum = someNumbers.min
```

Note that this throws an exception if the list is empty. From scala 2.13.x onwards, there will be a [minOption](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#minOption:Option[A]) method to handle such cases gracefully. For older versions you could use the `reduceOption` method as workaround:

```
someNumbers.reduceOption(_ min _)
someNumbers.reduceOption(Math.min)
```

Answer (score 4):

Add all numbers in the collection like the list and find a minimum of it.

```
scala> val list = List(2,3,7,1,9,4,5)
list: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 7, 1, 9, 4, 5)

scala> list.min
res0: Int = 1
```